# Displaying popup dialog when main dialog is on second monitor

Tags: mfc, multiple-monitors

I have an interesting situation.

You run any `CDialog` derived application and move it onto your second monitor.

You then invoke a popup dialog. I am finding that the popup dialog is being displayed in the center of the main monitor and not central to the parent dialog.

For example:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::OnOptionsPublishersDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        CPublishersDatabaseDlg dlgPublishers(this);

        dlgPublishers.DoModal();
    }
    catch (_com_error e)
    {
        LPCTSTR szError = e.ErrorMessage();
        AfxMessageBox(szError);
    }
    catch (CException* e)
    {
        e->Delete();
        AfxMessageBox(_T("CException"));
    }
}
```

How are we supposed to correctly invoke a child popup dialog central to the parent when the parent is on the second monitor?

Comment: I can't duplicate this behavior. Show the resource definition for the two dialogs. Also your operating system. Maybe you are calling `CenterWindow` in `OnInitDialog`, that would center your dialog to the nearest monitor (not necessarily the primary monitor)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It is a false alarm. I forgot that my window remembers it's last known location. That is whjy it was showing on the primary monitor. All is good. The reason I thought it was wrong was because CuteFTP Pro was behaving in the same way. Atleast my program is ok.